# Help me break my friend's code!

Tags: cipher

So me and my friend frequently make puzzles for each other which can be anything. I wasn't able to figure this one out so you guys might.

Those are the three strings he gave me. They are separate strings that all return the same result (they don't need to be combined or anything like that, he just gave me 3 so that it would be somehow easier to crack it apparently):

```
essentially snared aggie hafnium tit acrostically blueing casks handkerchief cries mcdonald parred incumbencies corundums spermatozoon rear insolence supercilious 

wadis administrator scragged subunits selfness persevering dreidel chartist poundkeeper mcdonald lavalava maybe apostrophizing secobarbital unwinder 

augustine pegged unravelled presides briefness rawhided ellipse aweigh bodkin cd exuberance quired regard ruinous excises
```

He was so nice to give me the result of what those 3 things would return if they where "cracked":

> redking

And he also gave me those tips:

> something is reversed
>  a word can only contain one letter
>  the letters q,x,y,z don't matter

So my task was to send him another string like those coded with his method with the same phrase.

Comment: each of those lines return the same result. Nothing needs to be added to any of those 3 lines to produce the result

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Find below the decoding method:

> Find the alphabet backwards and keep the letter just right of it.  More precisely, scan the words from right to left, but scan the words themselves from left to right.  And pick no more than one letter in each word.

Decoding:

> *essentially snared a**GG**ie ha**FN**ium tit acrostically blu**EI**ng casks han**DK**erchief cries m**CD**onald parred incum**BE**ncies corundums spermatozoon re**AR** insolence supercilious
>
>
>
>  wadis administrator scra**GG**ed subunits sel**FN**ess persevering dr**EI**del chartist poun**DK**eeper m**CD**onald lavalava may**BE** apostrophizing secob**AR**bital unwinder
>
>
>
>  augustine pe**GG**ed unravelled presides brie**FN**ess rawhided ellipse aw**EI**gh bo**DK**in **CD** exu**BE**rance quired reg**AR**d ruinous excises*

Comment: That might be it gonna ask him tommorow

Comment: I'll add that this only works if you don't use the same word twice for any letter (e.g., incumbencies in line 1 has a B and a C that would fit)

Comment: @TylerW my guess is the tips help you there the "something is reverse" is about searching for the phrase from behind and "a word can only contain one letter" means that the first one you find in a word counts and then you continue to the next word

Comment: @Vajura Ah yep, completely forgot that tip.

Comment: Very nice on that one

Comment: So I guess the final hint is to throw you off?

Comment: so, let him know that the 2nd one actually becomes LEDKING, as we should take the L from secobarbit**AL**, not the R

Comment: @SeanCheshire He said you have to first write down the words in the reverse order and then go from left to right searching for the letters and ignore other letters in a word if the first one matched. And yes this is the correct answear good job.

Comment: OK, I updated the answer.

Comment: [Please do not post an answer where all the content is hidden in spoiler markup](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1359/should-and-or-are-top-voted-answers-allowed-to-use-spoiler-tags/1424#1424). Your answer should make sense and be distinguishable from another answer to a reader who cannot or chooses not to read the spoiler block.

Comment: That makes sense.

Comment: The line wrapping in the spoiler block really confused meat first.  But now I understand.